# Problem with Case-sensitive Sort order for Search results in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: search-results, managed-property, sorting, search-results-webpart

Sort order for Search results in SharePoint 2013.it looks like it sorts the lowercase letters before/after all the upper case ones. So A-Za-z, not AaZz. Any ideas to customize that?